# Problem with a plot in ContourPlot3D using Table

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

people!

I'm trying to create a table with eight different contour plots in 3D using the following code:

```
    Timing[Table[
    ContourPlot3D[
    Sqrt[4/(Pi)^2] Sin[m x] Sin[n y] Sin[l z], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, 
    Pi}, {z, 0, Pi}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z     } , 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"m = ", m , " , n = ", n, " , l = ", l}], 
    Mesh -> None], {m , 2}, {n, 2}, {l, 2}]]
```

The problem is that the result yields a table in which appear planes in the contour plots that shouldn't be there. Image attached.

[image: why these planes]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "planes" are contours. If you want only 2 contours you have to specify: `Contours -> 2`:

```
Table[ContourPlot3D[
  Sqrt[4/(Pi)^2] Sin[m x] Sin[n y] Sin[l z], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, 
   Pi}, {z, 0, Pi}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"m = ", m, " , n = ", n, " , l = ", l}], 
  Mesh -> None, Contours -> 2], {m, 2}, {n, 2}, {l, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank u so much!